# unresolved identifier on .begin() and .end()?

Tags: c++, vector, identifier

i keep getting this error "unresolved identified" on `l_vector.begin()` and `l_vector.end`, specifically on the `begin` and `end` functions, why is it not recognizing these simple vector functions?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// function prototype
int FindIndexOfLargest(vector<int> l_vector);

int main() 
{
    int FindIndexOfLargest();
    return 0;
}

//function definition
int FindIndexOfLargest(vector<int> l_vector)
{

     vector<int>:: const_iterator iter;
     int current_max_location = 0;
     int current_max = 0;


    for(iter = l_vector.begin(); iter != l_vector.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if(*iter > current_max)
        {
            current_max_location = iter;
        }
        return current_max;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should handle the case of an empty vector. You should also return a value from the function. Otherwise, the code you wrote compiles fine.

Comment: alright, i will add those in.  I was trying to keep it simple during testing.

Comment: also you have a space (after ::) in the declaration of iter

Comment: @pm100 - but, to be clear, that's cosmetic; it doesn't affect the meaning of the code.

Comment: i never knew that - ty

Answer (score 0):

I see a few causes for compilation failure.

> > int FindIndexOfLargest();

You have to pass an `std::vector <int>` to this function when you call it in `main()`.

And finally, your function `int FindIndexOfLargest(vector<int> l_vector)` must return an `int` value.

An alternate way to write this function is to use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

```
std::size_t FindIndexOfLargest(const std::vector <int> &input)
{
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator max_value = 
        std::max_element(input.cbegin(), input.cend());

    if (max_value != input.cend()) {
        return std::distance (input.cbegin(), max_value);
    }

    // Otherwise, throw an expection or return an error value here.
}
```

Comment: I have modified it to return an int value.                                                       Can you explain  :You have to pass an std::vector <int> to this function when you call in main()."  Why does it need std if i've said that is my namespace?

Comment: @Battlefrisk The `std::` part is not the issue. The issue is that you are not passing any arguments to the function `FindIndexOfLargest()` when you call it in `main()`.

Comment: ah ok, so i made that modification and i edited it above.  Do you think you can explain to me why it's not letting me insert the current position of the iterator in int current_max_location?  I'm getting this in the online compiler (not netbeans tho?)                                                                                   57:34: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'int' in assignment

Comment: @Battlefrisk Please re-read my answer and my comments. You made no such modification, you just made your algorithm worse. [Here](https://ideone.com/azImfO) is a working example.

Comment: @Battlefrisk If your compiler does not support C++11 features, then you have to create a `std::vector`, fill it up with values, and then pass it to your `FindIndexOfLargest()` function that you call in `main()`.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/cojEtn) that does not use any complicated c++ features.